# python delete empty sub lists of list

Tags: python

I want to delete the empty sub list, some ways are failed, but other ways are successful. Why ?
The worry way:

```
data=[[],[],[],[],[]]
for rows in data:
    if len(rows)==0:
       list.remove(rows)
print data
```

the result is `[[],[]]`.It isn't my expected result `[]`

the correct way(my friend tell me,thank him):

```
list = [[],[],[],[],[]]
a=list(filter(lambda x: [] != x, list))
print a
```

the result is my expected empty list `[]`

Comment: it is because you are iterating through a list that changes size. I am surprised that you don't get an error with the first code

Comment: Whitefret is correct.  It's generally a bad idea to iterate over a list whilst you're deleting items from it.

Comment: @Whitefret python's list iterator is basically an increasing index until IndexError is raised. That also explains the observed result and why no error is raised. Doesn't mean one should rely on this behaviour though...

Comment: @IljaEverilä thanks for the precision !

Answer (score 3):

Avoid iterating over a list while doing the changes on it:

```
data=[[],[],[],[],[]]
for rows in data:
    if len(rows)==0:
       data.remove(rows)
print data
```

Instead, create a new list:

```
>>> lst = []
>>> data = [[],[],[],[1,2,3]]
>>> 
>>> for rows in data:
        if rows: #if rows is not an empty list
            lst.append(rows)


>>> lst
[[1, 2, 3]]
>>>
```

Same as you did with `filter` which creates a new object:

```
>>> lst = [[],[],[],[1,2,3],[1,],[], [4,5,6],[7]]
>>> lst = filter(list.__len__,lst)
>>> lst
[[1, 2, 3], [1], [4, 5, 6], [7]]
```

**EDIT**:

After doing some profiling, I got the following resutls:

```
>>> import timeit
>>> timeit.timeit('filter(list.__len__, lst)', setup='lst=[[],[],[],[1,2,3],[1,],[], [4,5,6],[7]]', number=1000000)
1.03789886128774
>>>
>>> timeit.timeit('filter(lambda x:x, lst)', setup='lst=[[],[],[],[1,2,3],[1,],[], [4,5,6],[7]]', number=1000000)
1.0035609489573218
>>>
>>> timeit.timeit('filter(None, lst)', setup='lst=[[],[],[],[1,2,3],[1,],[], [4,5,6],[7]]', number=1000000)
0.4335933814062045
>>>
>>> timeit.timeit('[l for l in lst if l]', setup='lst=[[],[],[],[1,2,3],[1,],[], [4,5,6],[7]]', number=1000000)
0.41073885410420985
```

Comment: You could convert the loop into a list comprehension: `lst = [rows for rows in data if rows]`

Comment: @ByteCommander .. Correct we could do that...

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> data=[[],[],[],[],[]]
>>> filter(lambda x:x,data)
[]

>>> data=[[],[],[],[],[1]] 
>>> filter(lambda x:x,data)
[[1]]
```

Comment: Instead of `lambda x:x` you can also pass `None` as first parameter to the `filter` builtin function to achieve the same i.e. elements that equal `False` if converted to boolean (like None, 0, False, empty collections, empty strings, ...) get filtered out.

Comment: thank you. exists this problem, change to  `filter(lambda x:len(x), data)`